# Having trouble with reinstalling GUI on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: network-manager

I was trying to download sketch when I really didn't realize it said it HAD to remove 1.5GB of dependencies (I thought it was install). Couldn't cancel it half way or tried to, ended up losing the GUI and a lot of other dependencies.

So far...

1. Majority of searches over google said to use sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^. Unfortunately, anything I try to download it always says i have broken packages.
2. Apart from no GUI, i noticed i have no access to the internet. I tried using an Ethernet cable..turns out it didn't work and for some strange reason it wouldnt work. Tried so many things such as changing the NetworkManager.conf file and the /etc/network/interfaces but nothing really seems to work for me.

Also I would like to add I am still in recovery mode trying to solve this, idk what else to do really. I can't come out of Ubuntu Emergency mode.

One method that's probably my last would be using someone else's computer and downloading a fresh install of ubuntu onto a USB and booting from it and reinstall Ubuntu. I don't want to lose my files!

I am a bit baffled on how I should continue to resolve this. Any help will be nice!

P.S. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Have you tried: `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: yeah, it still came up as broken packages or something similar to that wording.

Comment: Try also `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt install -f`. But, maybe, you need just reinstall your Ubuntu version. Or is there something very important could be lost? If your files are located in /home mount point for some partition /dev/sda5 or something, then just don't format it until reinstalling. It's like a disk D: in windows. Don't touch it, just reassign this partition to your /home mount point. My `df -h` says: `/dev/sdb1       229G   40G  177G  19% /home`

Comment: In case of reinstalling my Ubuntu I would leave /dev/sdb1 non formatted, so files on this drive will not be lost.

Comment: If you have no access to the internet, you could sideload the packages. Cache them **onto another machine** with `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get install --download-only <NameOfPackages>`. Then copy the files from `/var/cache/apt/archives` to a removable media (such as USB pen drive). You could then use something like `dpkg` or `gdebi` to install them from the USB on the affected machine.

Comment: @Gryu I really couldn't use `sudo apt update` as i couldn't connect to the internet. I gave up trying and just went with reinstallation. Now I am a bit stuck with some UEIF partitions for grub

Comment: @DanielMassey I have seen some posts about this, It uninstalled A LOT of packages, even went through the logs, was a bit sad. Ended with a fresh reinstallation but now trying to get rid of the grub partitions of the ubuntu systems left behind.